# Why am I getting "Expected closing bracket for IPv6 address at index" er

Tags: http, jmeter

I'm trying to manually post a form which is normally done automatically by Javascript, however I'm encountering the following error:

```
> java.net.URISyntaxException: Expected closing bracket for IPv6 address at index 15: https://[https://REDACTEDURL.co.uk:]/ssomanager/saml/SSO?
    at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.failExpecting(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parseServer(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parseAuthority(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URI.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.toURI(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:357)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1166)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1155)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:475)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:418)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:249)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I have configured the request as follows: enter image description here The variables are:

[image]

Variables are:

ManualServer_g1=REDACTEDURL.co.uk

ManualPath_g1=/ssomanager/saml/SSO

However the request is coming out like:

```
> POST https://[https://REDACTEDURL.co.uk:]/ssomanager/saml/SSO?

> POST data:
> 
> 
> [no cookies]
```

Any thoughts

Answer (score 1):

In Server Name you should use first group found in regular expression, Use:

```
${ManualServer_g1}
```

Instead of `${ManualServer_g0}`